# Flux TodoMVC: what for do they offer to install and run "react-boilerplate"?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I don't understand why they offer to install and run [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/petehunt/react-boilerplate). I read their [tutorial Todo-List](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html):

> ... and we can build off of `react-boilerplate` to get up and running quickly

and a little below

> The TodoMVC example has all this built into it as well...

What is the reason then to a) mention about `react-boilerplate`, b) offer to install it?

But, ok, I decide to install and try `react-boilerplate`. And there is nothing worth attention in that package. No any serious code, no any `.html`, no any server to run and see what the app does.

They write about `react-boilerplate`:

> Next run the npm scripts to get up and running: `npm install`, then `npm run build`, and lastly `npm start` to continuously build using Browserify

But that is not true. `react-boilerplate` doesn't have Browserify. It doesn't use it in any way. It has `src\index.js` file:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var requireStylesheet = require('stylesheets').requireStylesheet;

requireStylesheet(process.env.STATIC_ROOT + 'MyComponent.css');

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <span className="MyComponent">Hello, MyComponent!</span>;
  }
});

module.exports = MyComponent;
```

The file has `require`s. If, as they say, `react-boilerplate` uses Browserify then Browserify should create some large compiled `bundle.js` file with all requires inside. But it doesn't. It only compiles React components:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var requireStylesheet = require('stylesheets').requireStylesheet;

requireStylesheet(process.env.STATIC_ROOT + 'MyComponent.css');

var MyComponent = React.createClass({displayName: 'MyComponent',
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.span( {className:"MyComponent"}, "Hello, MyComponent!");
  }
});

module.exports = MyComponent;
```

Why `Flux Tutorial – Todo List` does offer to install `react-boilerplate`? How does `react-boilerplate` use Browserify?

Comment: Those docs are severely outdated. This is better, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html, but this link will give even better resources https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be an error. They probably mean https://github.com/christianalfoni/flux-react-boilerplate which includes the necessary dependencies.

Comment: You don't have to delete your answer in order to write a new one, just edit the first one! :)